# SQL Server date separator dot not working while inserting data

Tags: sql-server

When I insert a date like this '01.03.2020 21:35:12' it changes into '2020-01-03 21:35:12.000'.

I want to insert the date with DOT as the Date separator.

NOTE: I'm not using a stored procedure, just insert query.

Comment: DateTimes are not stored in SQL server with dashes or dots. They are stored as a number of days since January 1, 1900. They may be displayed with those separators, but that's a function of the code displaying the value. So the correct place to change the format will be related to whatever is displaying the DateTime or converting it to a string.

Comment: Why are you intentionally formatting your date in an ambiguous way? If I don't know whether you mean January 3rd or March 1st, you can't expect SQL Server to know.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inferior choice in format, because nobody reading that code can be certain whether you meant January 3rd or March 1st. You can get there this way, but it is ugly, unintuitive, and equally non-self-documenting:

```
DECLARE @d varchar(30) = '01.03.2020 21:35:12';

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @d, 104);
```

Much better to use a **standard, unambiguous** date format for literals. These are the only two formats not subject to misinterpretation by language, dateformat, or regional settings, and therefore don't need to be accompanied by cryptic style numbers:

```
DECLARE @d1 varchar(30) = '20200301 21:35:12',
        @d2 varchar(30) = '2020-03-01T21:35:12';

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @d1), CONVERT(datetime, @d2);
```

Background:

- [Recommended SQL Server Date Formats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9315/recommended-sql-server-date-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the display in SSMS from the YYYY-MM-DD TIME format. If you want to change the way you get the date back when selected, you can use the CONVERT or FORMAT functions.

CONVERT function: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

FORMAT function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

You may need to select your datetime twice with the CONVERT. Once for the date and once for the time in order to get the combination of formats you want.

-John

Comment: A caveat for `FORMAT()` - while more convenient and flexible than `CONVERT`, [it is twice as slow](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). That said, the OP is encountering this issue when *inserting* data, not when *displaying* it.